# I want to configure my NVIDIA Jetson card to function as a blockchain node, connecting it to my Quorum blockchain network

Tags: blockchain, iot, smartcontracts, nvidia-jetson-nano, quorum

I apologize for the confusion. Here's the rephrased paragraph in English:

I have set up a private blockchain on my PC by following the tutorial at https://docs.goquorum.consensys.net/tutorials/private-network/create-qbft-network. Now, I want to add a new node to my Quorum blockchain using an Nvidia Jetson Nano 2GB. I would like the Jetson Nano 2GB to function as a Quorum node. My objective is to send data from sensors to Quorum, and ensure that all nodes can access and view the sensor values.

I followed the tutorial mentioned at https://docs.goquorum.consensys.net/tutorials/private-network/adding-removing-qbft-validators, but I encountered issues with it. I'm confused about why the tutorial suggests using the command npx quorum-genesis-tool --validators 1 --members 0 --bootnodes 0 --outputPath artifacts when I already have a genesis file on another machine. My intention is to initialize my node using the existing genesis file and configure it accordingly.